# Google Speech to text throwing java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, speech-to-text

**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Below exception:

```
 03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): Key android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE expected String but value was a java.util.Locale.  The default value <null> was returned.
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Locale cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:921)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4822)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at ihn.<init>(PG:97)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at com.google.android.voicesearch.intentapi.IntentApiActivity.onCreate(PG:37)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    03-04 16:33:13.281 W/Bundle  ( 3741): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
```

Comment: Try hardcoding language like 
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

Comment: **Locale.getDefault().toString()** use this instead of just **Locale.getDefault()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hard coding language like

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```

instead of

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
```

check whether it works or not, if it works then you its the problem with the  `Locale.getDefault());`

your app can query for the list of supported languages by sending a `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS` ordered broadcast like so:

```
Intent detailsIntent =  new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(
            detailsIntent, null, new LanguageDetailsChecker(), null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

You can write the broadcast reciever like

```
public class LanguageDetailsChecker extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private List<String> supportedLanguages;

    private String languagePreference;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE))
        {
            languagePreference =
                    results.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);
        }
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES))
        {
            supportedLanguages =
                    results.getStringArrayList(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
        }
    }
}
```

Check this link out
[toolkit for using Android's Sensing capabilities](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib)